# 'Demand has risen' using 'there be'

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to express something like **demand for something has risen** using **there be** clause.

Is it OK to say **there has raised demand for something**?

Comment: Where is the form of the verb BE in your sentence?

Comment: You can say "X has raised demand for Y" but "There has raised" doesn't make any sense.  Maybe you're thinking of something like  "There has been increased demand for Y"?

Comment: "There has been a rising demand for ..." using *to rise* instead of *to raise*.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the phrase does not contain a verb indicating existence (like 'to be' or 'to exist') it cannot be a existential ('there be') clause.

The current verb is a form of 'have': indicating possession by something and not existence

The verb form is correct, but not the root verb itself. Swap the 'has' for the correct form of 'be' (third person singular in this case) and you have a valid existential clause.

> There **is** raised demand for something.